# Using the App Store to distribute games to testers?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, app-store, game-center

I'm working on an iPhone game and have just added some Game Center features. Testers find Game Center annoying to test because they have to log out of GC with their real accounts and then log in with a sandbox account.

I've been considering submitting it to the App Store but setting the release date far in the future so I can distribute to my testers with promo codes. That would allow them to test my game using their live Game Center accounts.

Besides the fact that new beta releases would take a week to reach testers because of the review process, are there any other problems with using the live App Store to distribute to testers?

Comment: Yeah...your app will be rejected if it has bugs...which it surely will if it is in testing.

Comment: No bugs, just missing features, none of which would be critical enough for Apple to reject.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the minor inconvenience of having to log out of a regular game centre account into a sandbox one is trivial compared to that of being dependant on Apple's approval process to test features on the fly. This accompanied by the fact that if any bugs are found the app won't be approved outright make this a pretty unviable option.

Comment: Depending on the approval process is annoying to me, logging in and out of Game Center is annoying to my testers. Since my testers are friends and family kindly volunteering their time, the annoyance reduces the amount that the game center features actually get used.

Comment: If you think *that* reduces the amount of time...what do you think that the week - 10 days wait each time will do to the rest of the features?  Also, you will waste Apple's time with your constant updating...(they will probably realize what you are doing and follow the below mentioned guideline 2.9) the store is not your testing tool.

Comment: To the original question.  I agree with this answer.  It will be a very hard road to use the app store for beta testing.  You SHOULD NOT do this. Not to mention the very long turn around time every time you need to send out a new build.  Use ad hoc like you're supposed to.  Promo codes are strictly forbidden and you won't get past the app review board. If you do and they find out that you're purposely breaking the rules your app will get pulled, if not your developer agreement.  Plus it's just darn unprofessional.  It's not what the app store is for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your game has to not look like beta test or demo, but appear fully functional, for Apple to approve it.  So you will have to remove (hide) all game elements and UI that aren't working or finished yet, including any in the game instructions.
2. You can't prevent anyone from downloading or buying it after it is approved and you release it for sale. So your app may get 1-star ratings from random-drive-by downloaders.  (Maybe you can limit your exposure by setting the price really high, making the app available for sale in only 1 country starting at midnight, and removing it from sale as soon as your testers download it using redeem codes.)

Comment: You may need to become more familiar with the App Store. I absolutely can prevent anyone from buying it, there are even two ways to accomplish it. One, as I mention in the question, I could set the release date far into the future. Two, I could specify which regional stores it is available in, and then deselect everything.

Comment: Using only a single country store I mentioned, but then it's available to everyone/anyone in that country.  And if you set the release date far into the future, how will your beta testers be able to find and download the app from the App store?

Comment: From my question: I would "distribute to my testers with promo codes". This works with NO countries enabled, or with a future release date.

Comment: Interesting!  Is this App store behavior documented anywhere?